# How to configure domain for a exists domain

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

to begin with, I have a very little knowledge about the configuration, but I have a question to ask.

I have two website with the domain

1. website1.domain.com
2. websites.domain.com

At each domain, I buy another domain for them.

1. website1.com
2. website2.com

I would like to ask, how can I configure the website1.com and website2.com to forward into website1.domain.com and website2.domain.com?

When a user goes to website1.com, it will NOT REDIRECT to website1.domain.com, but still be the same URL (website1.com)? And how can I use Let's Encrypt to config the SSL for each website?

Note:

1. I am using Nginx to configure the domain for website1.domain.com and website2.domain.com

It's the same how WordPress let their user to configure their own domain on their personal WordPress site. I am not an expert in DevOps, so can you guys please give me a solution, or some keyword to research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Configure the correct DNS records

Point the DNS host/domain names for which you want show websites to the IP-address of your webserver.

## Configure the web server

Like all modern web servers nginx allows you to assign multiple DNS host/domain names to a single virtual server with the [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) directive.

```
server {
    server_name website1.example.com website1.com;
    
    location / {
      root    /var/www/virtual/website1.example.com/htdocs;
    }
}
server {
    server_name website2.example.com website2.com;

    location / {
      root    /var/www/virtual/website2.example.com/htdocs;
    }
}
```

## Let's Ecrypt

It really depends on how you configured Let's Encrypt before but you can add additional domain/host-names to an existing Let's Encrypt certificate configuration.

To add website1.com to an existing certificate use for example:

```
certbot --cert-name website1.example.com -d website1.example.com -d website1.com
```